# Hibernate slow sql not logged

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, hikaricp

Problem with logging sql statement wrapped with Hikari.

I have hibernate property:

```
hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS=50
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW" level="info
```

but in log I get only class names instead of query

> SlowQuery: 64 milliseconds. SQL:
> 'HikariProxyPreparedStatement@1310910690 wrapping
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@33cffb6d

how can I log slow query statement wrapped by hikari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/7030
An Hibernate Leader's PR today solve the issue.
Merged on Hibernate.main, will be available on next 6.3

Answer (score 4):

The problem is known and already open at Hibernate: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13741

Comment: I am looking for a work around or any solution https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/5082#issuecomment-1267281714

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 6.3.1.Final and it is still now working. I get Slow query took 130 milliseconds [HikariProxyPreparedStatement@1859255735 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@1aaab222]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35025177)