# Finding the indexes that are missing in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have a spring project with many Entities and a complex relationship between entities. I would like to automatically find the indexes that are missing so that I could create those indexes. Are there any tools that help in achieving this? We are using Hibernate ORM and Oracle Database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474970/hibernate-slow-sql-not-logged/76723050#76723050
SLOW_QUERY_LOG of Hibernate will now really working, in next 6.2

Answer (score 0):

- There is a new useful feature in Hibernate: SLOW_QUERY_LOG(LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS). It would help you if it really worked (HHH-13928)
- There is cool (but very expensive) tool Dynatrace, which can tell you relation between a slow REST API call and particular slow SQL
- And then there are Oracle's native tools like Diagnostic pack and Tunning pack. But those will not show you relation between slow SQL and piece in you code which called it.
- There is common issued when there are missing indexes on FK keys. In most cases those are a must. https://www.orafaq.com/node/2935